# google Api adsense (401) Invalid Credentials

Tags: adsense-api

I have AdSense account with custom channels on it I make every thing but there are two problems:

1. I get reports for all account i need to get reports for one channel
   based on channel id
2. I need to get reports for all users without they have my google to
   access whene i save my details in database

My data:

```
{
  "access_token" : "XXXX.XXXX",
  "token_type" : "XXXX",
  "expires_in" : XXXX,
  "created" : XXXX
}
```

My update statements:

```
$access_token_update = json_decode($access_token);
$access_token_update->created = time();
```

I'm getting this error message:

> (401) Invalid Credentials

My code:

```
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
$service= new Google_Service_AdSense($client);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do steps in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc

save code from results example

```
{
 "access_token": "XXXXXXXX", 
 "token_type": "XXXX", 
 "expires_in": XXXX, 
 "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXX"
```

}

then update your file as the following

```
$access_token = "from database or file or what you want to save"; // this will be code you got by doing steps in this video.
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$access_token_json = json_decode($access_token);
$client->refreshToken($access_token_json ->refresh_token);
$service= new Google_Service_AdSense($client);
```

enjoy :) thanks